# Fullsimplify does not simplify Abs'[1.-a]

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have to simplyfy an expression involving `Abs`'
This works:

```
FullSimplify[Abs'[1 - a], a ∈ Reals]
```

> Sign[1 - a]

but this does not:

```
FullSimplify[Abs'[1. - a], a ∈ Reals]
```

> Derivative[1][Abs][1. - a]

the problem seems to be the 1., how can i get around this ?

Comment: Something like: `FullSimplify[Rationalize[Abs'[1. - a]], a \[Element] Reals]`?

Comment: What about `FullSimplify[D[Abs[c - a], a], 
  Assumptions -> {a \[Element] Reals, c \[Element] Reals}] /. c -> 1.`

Comment: Both works. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mathematica does not have a rule for the derivative of `Abs`. Assuming that the term arose from taking the derivative with respect to `a` then taking the derivative of `Abs[1-a]` results in

```
D[Abs[1 - a], a]
```

> -Derivative[1][Abs][1 - a]

which would recurse forever if it evaluated. Note

```
Plot[{Abs[1 - a], -Sign[1 - a]}, {a, -5, 5},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Graphically, the derivative is `-Sign[1 - a]` except when `a == 1`

If dealing with real functions, before taking the derivative of a function containing `Abs` the function should have the terms with `Abs` converted to the `Sqrt` of the square of the argument to `Abs`.

```
Simplify[D[Sqrt[(1 - a)^2], a], Element[a, Reals]]
```

> Piecewise[{{-1, a < 1}}, 1]

```
Simplify[% == -Sign[1 - a], a != 1]
```

> True

Answer (score 9):

If you want to incorporate the realness assumption directly into the evaluation of the derivative, you can define it for all subsequent computations by setting

```
Derivative[1][Abs][x_] := Sign[x]

Abs'[1. - a]

(* ==> Sign[1. - a] *)
```

This works because `Derivative` is not a protected function. Of course, just as with the replacement by $\sqrt{x^2}$, this is only valid if you know you're dealing with purely real variables.

To undo the above definition, you can do this:

```
Derivative[1][Abs][x_] =.
```

**Edit for more generality**

If you want to go this route, then the issue might occur that you also want to define the derivative to give an answer at the vertex of the absolute-value function. The correct answer is the Dirac delta function, and to make this come out correctly one could define the general $n$-th derivative as follows:

```
Derivative[n_][Abs][x_] := 2 Derivative[n - 1][(HeavisideTheta[#] - 1/2)&][x]
```

The main advantage is that you also get the delta function in the *second* derivatitve that incorporates the special case where the derivative jumps:

```
Abs''[1. - a]

(* ==> 2 DiracDelta[1. - a] *)
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems no one has mentioned [`ComplexExpand[expr]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html), which "expands `expr` assuming that all variables are real," as a potential solution; it certainly applies in the example, since `a` is explicitly assumed to be real.

`ComplexExpand` will work on the derivative of `Abs`:

```
ComplexExpand[Abs'[1 - a]]
(*  1/Sqrt[(1 - a)^2] - a/Sqrt[(1 - a)^2]  *)
```

but in some cases, it might be more convenient to expand absolute values in the function:

```
D[ComplexExpand[-Abs[1 - a]], a]
(*  (1 - a)/Sqrt[(1 - a)^2]  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

As of V11.1 there's [`RealAbs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealAbs.html), whose derivative exists and evaluates automatically:

```
RealAbs'[1. - x]
```

> ```
> (1. - x)/RealAbs[1. - x]
> ```