# How can evaluate this function

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

Suppose this function `F[c_, n_, s_] := Module[{}, Abs[s - 1 + (-1 + c)^n]]`

I calculate its second derivative on c

```
In[64]:= D[F[c, n, s], {c, 2}]

f[c_, n_, s_] :=Module[ {}, (-1 + c)^(-2 + n) (-1 + n) n Derivative[1][
   Abs][-1 + (-1 + c)^n + s] + (-1 + c)^(-2 + 2 n)
   n^2 (Abs^\[Prime]\[Prime])[-1 + (-1 + c)^n + s]]

Manipulate[Plot[f[c, n, 0], {c, 0, 1}], {n, 0, 10},{s,0,1}]
```

`Manipulate` does not work because the function `f` does not get evaluated.
example:

```
f[0, 2, 1]=2. Derivative[1][Abs][1.] + 4. (Abs^\[Prime]\[Prime])[1.]
```

Comment: *Mathematica* does not know how to handle the derivative of the absolute value in the general complex case. This has been discussed before here: [`Fullsimplify` does not simplify `Abs'[1.-a]`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69077/27951). A workaround could be to use `Sqrt[(...)^2]` instead of `Abs[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

The answser shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69077/fullsimplify-does-not-simplify-abs1-a) suggests that one shoud use `Sqrt[a^2]` rather than `Abs[a]` if one is going to need the derivative.

Applying that to your problem results in:

```
F[c_, n_, s_] := Sqrt[(s - 1 + (-1 + c)^n)^2]
```

Note that there is no need to use `Module` as far as I can see.

And now

```
f[c_, n_, s_] = D[F[c, n, s], {c, 2}]
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If `n` is other than an integer `f` will produce imaginary numbers. Limiting `n` to integers in `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[c, n, s], {c, 0, 1},
   PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Black],
 {{n, 7}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{s, 0.5}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]