# Meaning of Abs´?

Tags: evaluation, syntax

A friend showed me the code below.

```
r[i_] := {x[i, t], y[i, t], z[i, t]};
rji = r[i] - r[j];
solap = 2 a - Norm[rji];
FullSimplify[D[solap, t]]
```

I'm unsure about what she's trying to calculate, but we're both curious about the output produced:

[image]

What is `Abs´`?

Comment: Put your cursor on it and press F1, thank me later.

Comment: @paw: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sebmx5wxkwofnjw/Prime.PNG?dl=0

Comment: So @Paw, where in that directed documentation does it address the `Abs` followed by a tick?

Comment: Indeed, the help on `Prime` is not enlightening at all, unfortunately. The `'` indicates a first derivative. This is linked with asking to calculate the derivative using `D`. However, Mathematica does not have a rule for the derivative of `Abs`. See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69077/27951 for a discussion.

Comment: @andandandand Sorry, didn't see the tick. The problem is related to the derivative of Abs. Try `FullSimplify[D[ComplexExpand[solap], t]]` instead.

Comment: The derivative of `Abs` is not defined so it remains unevaluated as `Abs'`. If you ae dealing with real-valued functions then use the substitution `Abs[x_] :> Sqrt[x^2]` prior to taking the derivative.

Comment: Try `solap = 2 a - ComplexExpand@Norm[rji]`, too.