# What is preventing Mathematica from simplifying $-\frac{1}{3}\frac{d}{dx}\ln|1+x^{-3}|$ even when assuming $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

For the input

```
D[-1/3*Log[Abs[1 + x^(-3)]], x]
```

the output is

```
Derivative[1][Abs][1 + 1/x^3]/(x^4*Abs[1 + 1/x^3])
```

so I put

```
FullSimplify[D[-1/3*Log[Abs[1 + x^(-3)]], x], Element[x, Reals]]
```

to tell that `Abs` only takes real number arguments, but still the output is

```
Derivative[1][Abs][1 + 1/x^3]/(x^4*Abs[1 + 1/x^3])
```

What is preventing Mathematica from simplifying the output to

```
1/(x^4 + x)
```

and how can I get the expected result?

Comment: Try `Simplify[D[-1/3*Log[RealAbs[1 + x^(-3)]], x], x \[Element] Reals]`.  The complex `Abs[x]` is not complex-differentiable at any `x`. (Alternatively, you can use `ComplexExpand`.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fullsimplify does not simplify Abs'\[1.-a\]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69077/fullsimplify-does-not-simplify-abs1-a) Also: [Derivative of the Absolute Value Function in Mathematica looks very different from the actual answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47100/derivative-of-the-absolute-value-function-in-mathematica-looks-very-different-fr)

Comment: Abs on the real line is the integral of the Sign distribution:  Abs[x] =Integrate[Sign[x],{x,0,x]]. As a complex function, its differentiable exept at z=0  but not complex differentiable, it has the simple form Abs[z]= (z Conjugate[z])^(1/2). On the real line Sqrt(x^2). The  ( #^2)^(1/2)&  function is working as expected with the jump over the imaginary axis.